# Selenium IDE - Enter values in to dynamic fields

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

So first time posting, and I am not even sure `Selenium IDE` can handle what I want.

So on the web page I have 10 quantity fields (its a simple e-commerce site)
And I want to populate these 10 Quantity fields with values, however the `id` of these Qty fields can change.

e.g

```
Command          Target                Value

type           id=qtyField_124098        1

type           id=qtyField_124099        2           etc.
```

Is there an easy way to represent the `Target` by position. So I could put a value of 1 into the first Qty field, and 2 into the second Qty field.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to change your `locator` from the `id` to `xpath`. As such you could use something like `//input[n]` but obviously you'd change based on what is the actual `xpath` value for those fields.

EDIT:

With an example:

```
<div>
    <input> </input>
    <input> </input>
</div>
```

To reference the first `<input> your`xpath` would be

```
//div/input[1]
```

the second would be

```
//div/input[2]
```

Obviously, in most cases `xpath` expressions will be more complicated than that but hopefully this gives you a starting point.

Comment: how to work with //input[n], something with examples. because for me it cant able to find out.

Answer (score 0):

As this code helps me to find values dynamically and helped me, hope it will also help you

```
click   name=cmb_text_xxx
mouseOver   css=a:contains("xxx")
mouseDown   css=a:contains("xxx")
click       css=a:contains("xxx")
```